# os.rename skip values in the file name

Tags: python-3.x

When rewriting the name of files in a folder in a loop, I noticed that when renaming many numerical values are skipped. For example, after image29, image31 will immediately follow. What is my problem?

```
import os

from glob import glob

k=0

for filename in glob('D:/Dataset/Candidate/*jpg'):
    k = k+1
    os.rename(filename, 'D:/Dataset/Candidate/crop_image'+str(k)+'.jpg')
```

Comment: Do all your rename operations succeed? (.. I now see that it [throws an error](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) when not, so if it did you probably would have noticed that ...)

Comment: The operation is successful and error free. But in the file names such omissions always come across.

Comment: Can you try `print(filename, 'D:/Dataset/Candidate/crop_image'+str(k)+'.jpg')` to track down what each iteration is doing?